# What does ^= mean in Java?

Tags: java, binary, operators

I have seen the following code in HashMap.java.

```
    h ^= k.hashCode();
    // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
    // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
    // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).
    h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
    return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
```

A few random inputs produced an output similar to addition, but following code resulted in 0

```
   int p = 10;
    p ^= 10;
    System.out.println("_______ " + p);
```

Comment: Consider this one `char ch = '1';
        ch ^= Long.MIN_VALUE;`  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `^=` operator does an XOR with the variable on the left and the operand, then does an assignment to that variable of the result.

XOR something with itself and you get zero. It is an efficient way to set a register to zero as it doesn't move any memory.

Answer (score 1):

`^` is known as [XOR (Exclusive disjunction or exclusive or)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or), a logical operator, which follows:

```
1 xor 1 = 0
1 xor 0 = 1
0 xor 1 = 1
0 xor 0 = 0
```

as  `p^=10` is equivalent to:

```
p = p ^ 10; or,  p = p xor 10
```

with `p = 10` your operation is simply: , `(10 ^ 10)`, which will result in `0`

Answer (score 1):

`^=` is bitwise exclusive OR and assignment operator. `x ^= 2` is same as `x = x ^ 2`.

Answer (score 1):

^ is the symbol for a logical XOR (Exclusive OR).

When placed before an equals sign, this means 'XOR myself with the given value, and write the result back to myself'. a ^= value is the same as saying a = a ^ value.

It might make it clearer if done with other operators, such as add:

E.g:

```
int counter = 14;

 // Add 20 to counter (could also be written counter = counter + 20):
counter += 20;

// Counter is now 34
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a [**compound assignment operator**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) in java:

`x op= y` is equivalent to `x = x op y` (loosely speaking, see above link).

For example:

`x += y;` is equivalent to `x = x + y;`

`x -= y;` is equivalent to `x = x - y;`

and so on ...

---

For reference, this is the [complete list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.12) of all such operators in java:

`+=  -=  *=  /=  &=  |=  ^=  %=  <<=  >>=  >>>=`

Comment: With an implicit cast as well. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ya, I didn't know how to put it without making it over complicated :-)

Comment: The examples I like is `char ch = '0'; ch *= 1.1;` and `ch` is `'4'`